# WInUI3 ListView Item not showing border when selected

Tags: user-interface, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I'm trying to create a ListView that shows a border around the items(which are images) when the items are selected, but without success. I'm setting `SelectedBorderThickness`, but there is no change.
What could be the problem?

This is the code:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewName"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="0"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True"
          SelectionMode="Multiple"
          SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged"
          AllowDrop="True"
          CanDragItems="True"
          CanReorderItems="False"
          DragItemsStarting="OnDragStarted">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root"
                                               SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="False"
                                               CheckHintBrush="#FF0000"
                                               CheckBoxBrush="#00000000"
                                               ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                               DragBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                               DragForeground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                               FocusBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush}"
                                               FocusSecondaryBorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                               PlaceholderBackground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                               PointerOverBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"
                                               PointerOverForeground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"
                                               PressedBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"
                                               DisabledOpacity="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}"
                                               DragOpacity="1"
                                               ReorderHintOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                               HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                               ContentMargin="1"
                                               CheckMode="Overlay"
                                               BorderThickness="3"
                                               BorderBrush="#FF0000"
                                               SelectedBorderThickness="2"
                                               SelectedBorderBrush="#FF0000"></ListViewItemPresenter>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Data">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind FullPath}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a known [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6595) with `ListViewItemPresenter` and seems that some properties are ignored.

You could try the new `ItemsView` control. It comes with borders on selected items by default.

```xml
<ItemsView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items}" />
```

Comment: I have a [video](https://youtu.be/Unr5zbIfdZk?si=ZybKlwkiacJVMib-) about the `ItemsView` if you are interested.